# How to add an attribute to the finish button within jQuery-Steps?

Tags: jquery-steps

TLDR: How would one add an 'id' attribute to the finish button within jQuery.Steps.js?

When the finish button is called it looks like this within HTML:

```
<a href="#finish" role="menuitem">Finish</a>
```

This is what I want it to look like:

```
<a href="#finish" role="menuitem" id="example1">Finish</a>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Add this it works

```
onInit :function (event, current) {
   $('.actions a[href=#finish]').attr('id', 'example1');
}
```

Comment: That didnt work for me, I had to encapsulate the href with double quotes for it to work like so '.actions a[href="#finish"]'

Answer (score 0):

You can define a class for this element and choose a selector for that class in below statement to add id named example1 to Finish element.

```
$('.some_selector').attr('id', 'example1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
onInit :function (event, current) {
    $('.actions a[href=\\#finish]').attr('id', 'FinishButton');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your steps

```
onInit: function (event, currentIndex) {
    $('.actions a[href="#finish"]').attr('id', "example1");
},
```